# TeamsInfo.getMember() deprecation affecting botbuilder-java?

Tags: botframework

Can I get confirmation that changes described on Microsoft's documentation for [Teams Bot API Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/team-chat-member-api-changes) (happening by "late" 2022) also affect the [botbuilder-java sdk](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java)? There's nothing I could find about that in the docs or in the botbuilder-java github repo, and no deprecation warnings in the code either (running latest 4.14.2 version).

I accidentally stumbled upon that page and I'm worried especially about whether the `email` field will stop coming from `TeamsInfo.getMember()` calls.

Comment: I think when a specific library is deprecated, other bot framework languages match it as well.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, I wanted to point this out somewhere in case other people come across this and on the off chance the library maintainers do look at stackoverflow and want to add deprecation or comments to the lib.

Comment: This seems to be pretty dead.  I thought today to be "late 2022" so I checked if my stuff, which I haven't worked on for over a year, is now broken. It isn't. Google turns up a version of this Microsoft doc from 2020 with almost identical wording. Just the year has changed. And some github comment saying it won't come in 2022: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/6906#issuecomment-1243667598